# Wirkt das Wort „Abendland“ islamfeindlich?

Tags: etymology, sociolinguistics

Auf einem aus einer Pegida-**Gegen**demo stammenden Plakat lautet es:

> „Allein das Wort Abendland ist rückschrittlich.“

Zur mutmaßlichen unangenehmen Bedeutung des Wortes findet man in Wikipedia:

> „In Deutschland entwickelten, von Novalis angeregt, die Brüder August Wilhelm Schlegel und Friedrich Schlegel eine Europakonzeption, die sich auf kulturelle Traditionen stützte. Das Abendland umfasste ihrer Vorstellung nach alle Länder, die durch ihr romanisches, germanisches und christliches Erbe zu einem **einzigen europäischen Kulturraum in Antinomie zu einem islamisch** gedachten Orient oder Morgenland vereint waren.“ [[1]](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abendland)

Im *Pegida*-Kontext findet man schon das Wort nicht ganz nett. Aber sollte man das Wort *Abendland* (und in dem Fall vermutlich auch *Morgenland*) stets, auch in anderen Kontexten, vermeiden? Wirkt das Wort überall quasi islamfeindlich, oder nur in diesem Kontext? Kann man seinen religiösen Ursprung loswerden, oder wird der im Ohr des Muttersprachlers immer hervorgerufen?

*Nach meiner Meinung wird ja hier nicht gefragt, trotzdem hatte ich immer dessen Ursprung direkt stets mit Sonnenuntergängen (und -aufgängen für Morgenland) verbunden – nie mit Religion.*

Comment: Was hat das Zitat von der Gegendemo mit Deiner Frage zu tun? Islamfeindlich oder rückschrittlich sind zwei Paar Schuhe.

Comment: Zu schreiben "Im Pegida-Kontext findet man schon das Wort nicht ganz nett" ist verwirrend. Ist mit dem Kontext das Feld der Teilnehmer gemeint oder ist der Themenkomplex mit Anhängern und Gegnern der Pegidaproteste? Falls letzteres gemeint ist, dann ist bei so konträren Gruppen kaum mit einer gemeinsamen Bewertung zu rechnen. Falls nicht, so wäre zu erklären, wieso ausgerechnet die Pegidaanhänger das Wort nicht nett finden - wenn, dann scheint ja eher das Gegenteil der Fall. Dass man Wörter stets vermeiden sollte ist auch eine zugespitzte Aussage die man erst mal begründen müsste.

Comment: Die Verwendung von Abendland (und Morgenland) zeugt höchstens von einem gewissen Grad an Geschichtsverständnis. Das Wort an sich ist so schlimm wie "Zahnbürste"

Answer (score 9):

Meiner Meinung nach nicht. Wüsste auch nicht, wieso es so klingen sollte. Wenn, dann klingt es durch die Person, die es benutzt, und den Kontext , in dem es benutzt wird, so. In so einem Kontext kann aber auch "Deutschland" schnell nationalistisch rüberkommen.

Comment: Das ist leider ein bloßer Meinungsbeitrag. Wir sollten hier versuchen, eine deskriptive Antwort zu geben, also eher zu beschreiben, wie der Begriff verwendet und verstanden wird, als wie er verwendet und verstanden werden sollte. Hast du Belege dafür, dass deine Bewertung die allgemein in der Sprache geteilte ist?

Answer (score 8):

Für mich ist das weniger eine Frage der Religion als der Kultur. Man muss das auch aus dem Weltbild der damaligen Zeit sehen: es gab Europa, das kannte man, und dann gab es das aus damaliger Sicht weit entfernte, doch relativ nahe Land im Osten, das eine andere Kultur besaß und mit dem man regelmäßig im Clinch lag (Türkenkriege, Kreuzzüge). Dabei muss angemerkt werden, dass wir von denen zunächst mehr zu lernen hatten als die von uns.

Heute ist der Begriff definitiv veraltet. Rückschrittlich - nun ja, es gibt einerseits immer noch eine Gegensätzlichkeit, andererseits auch moderne, weltlich orientierte Staaten. Teilweise leider "gab", wie Iran, Syrien, Libyen. Das "Morgenland" ist nicht mehr so homogen wie früher. Das ist letztlich eine Frage der Überzeugung und nicht der Sprache (ich würde ihn nicht verwenden).

Frei verwendbar sind sie jedoch nicht, etwa "abendländisches Klima" für "europäisches Klima".

Comment: Zusammengefasst: "Abend-/Morgenland" im historischen Kontext benutzt ist ok, auf heute bezogen mehr als fragwürdig.

Comment: Wer ist "wir" und "denen" im ersten Absatz, letzter Satz? Der Satz 'Teilweise leider "gab"...' hat kein Verb und ist vollkommen unverständlich. Das 'ihn' im letzten Satz des zweiten Absatzes bezieht sich auf wen?

Answer (score 4):

Per se ist der Begriff *Abendland* nicht islamfeindelich; er wird allerdings so gut wie immer ab- und ausgrenzend eingesetzt. In den vergangenen zweihundert Jahren diente er den jeweiligen Reaktionären als ideologische Grundlage.

Novalis’ Konzeption eines Abendlandes, dargelegt in seinem Fragment *Die Christenheit oder Europa* von 1799, definiert eine Gegenposition zu den Ideen der Aufklärung und der französischen Revolution. Der Begriff selbst kommt zwar in dem Essay nicht vor, jedoch greifen die Gebrüder Schlegel in ihren Schriften auf die Vorarbeiten von Novalis zurück. Der reaktionäre (katholische) Flügel der Romantik strebte einen nicht säkularen Ständestaat an, wie es ihn vorgeblich im Mittelalter gab. Das kulturpessimistische Werk von Oswald Spengler, *Untergang des Abendlandes*, erschienen kurz nach dem ersten Weltkrieg, erkennt in den modernen Staatsideen (Liberalismus, Sozialismus, Kommunismus) die Anzeichen des Verfalls – und ist bis heute die Bibel des reaktionären Bildungsbürgertums.

Von besonderer Abscheulichkeit sind die Abendlandtheorien der Nationalsozialisten: Vermischt mit ihrem Blut- und Rasseunsinn warben sie vor allem in der zweiten Phase des Krieges mit einem obskuren Abendland bei den verbündeten und den unterdrückten Völkern für ihren Weltanschauungskrieg gegen die Sowjetunion, inklusive der Aufstellung einer wallonischen SS-Division *Charlemagne*.

Leider Gottes hat die junge Bundesrepublik unter zwei Aspekten an die braunen Vorgaben angeknüpft: Zum einen wurde der Begriff eine wichtige Grundlage der Ideologie des kalten Krieges, zum anderen aber konnte Adenauer seinen nationalistisch gesonnenen Parteifreunden und Koalitionspartnern die Westintegration schmackhaft machen. So konnten sich zum Beispiel in den fünfziger und sechziger Jahren an der „abendländischen Akademie“ in Eichstätt Monarchisten und Anhänger eines Ständestaates ungehindert austoben. Die Mehrheit von ihnen waren übrigens Hochschullehrer, Ministerialbeamte, Abgeordnete, welche alle irgendwann einmal einen Eid auf das Grundgesetz geleistet hatten.

PEGIDA knüpft genau an diese antidemokratischen und antipluralistischen Traditionen an: Dieses Mal sind es keine Jakobiner, jüdischen Untermenschen oder Bolschewisten, welche die primitivsten Instinkte des selbst definierten Kulturträgers ansprechen, sondern Moslems.

Die Erfahrung lehrt also: **Wer Abendland sagt, meint Hetze gegen andersstämmige, andersdenkende, andersgläubige … also überhaupt Menschen!**

Comment: Begriffe, die etwas taugen, dienen meist dazu eine Sache von anderen Sachen abzugrenzen. Bei Dir klingt das aber wie ein Vorwurf. Benutzte Karl May nicht auch oft die Begriffe, ohne aber den Orient abzuwerten? Ist Orient-Okzident nicht auch die gleiche Distinktion?

Answer (score -3):

Was sollte an Wörtern wie Abend und Land islamfeindlich sein? Genauso könnte man sagen Tageszeitung ist islamfeindlich. Das ist dümmliche Volksdemagogie. Wo wird schon der Begriff Abendland gebraucht? Doch eigentlich nur in älteren Geschichtsbüchern oder ähnlichen Werken. Heute sagt man Westeuropa und der Nahe Osten. Wie gesagt, das ist dümmliche Polemik.

Comment: Du sagst einerseits, das Wort werde nicht mehr allgemein benutzt, und weist andererseits den Gedanken, es dennoch zu benutzen könne weltanschauliche Gründe haben, als absurd zurück. Logisch ist das nicht.